# AS3 adding MouseEvent at once on multiple movieclips and run the same function which tell me which movieclip clicked and executed it

Tags: actionscript-3, target

I have 10 movieclips with instance name h1 to h10 which I'm using in array.
so I need coding, using 'for loop' to add EventListeners to all of them at once to execute same function.

And also want to know which movieclip is CLICKED and executed that function.

```
var hit:Array = [h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10];
var i:int;

for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    hit[i].buttonMode=true;
    hit[i].useHandCursor=true;
    hit[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fun1);            
}

function fun1()
{
    trace();          //    Which movieclip h(?) executed this function.    //

    switch(Which movieclip h(?) executed this function)
    {
        case h1: do something; break;
        .
        .
        .
        case h10: do something; break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it with currenTarget, in this case it returns mouse downed object

```
function fun1(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        switch (e.currentTarget)
        {
            case  h1 :
                break;
            case h2:
                break;
          //e.t.c
        }
    }
```